# PowerShell: How to export a function from the module file psm1 and as external ps1 file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Im trying to find out how i can both export a module member (function) that is written within the psm1 file and a member function that is written within its own ps1 file.
But both need to be exported as a member of the same module/project ...

eg the first function is too small or too simpleton to not have its own file, the second function is an advanced function that does need its own file to keep an overview of the whole shabang ...

Now how would i have exported both and even assign an alias to both cases ...

Can anyone explain how i would achieve that, my tries result in errors so far, altho i achieved both seperatly.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Im just trying to find out how to do this, because for me it seems to be one or the other, im not solving anything other then incoorporating a small function within the psm1 file and let have a bigger function have its own ps1 file and then still have them both exported from the same module. I can only get one way to work at a time for me, and not simulateniously ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried dot sourcing?

It won't load the ps1 as part of the module (For that the function would need to be IN the module and not in a separate ps1 file) but it will still load the functions from it.

```
# Load the module
Import-Module ".\MyPowershellModule.psm1"

# Load the ps1
. ".\MyPowershellScript.ps1"

# Use a function from ps1
FunctionFromPs1 -ThisParam -ThatParam

# Use a function from module
FunctionFromModule -ThisParam -ThatParam
```

The only other way i can think of (and i would **strongly** advise against this) is to dot source the ps1 in your module and load the module

Is there a reason you can't add the function to your module? Module are supposed to be a large repository of functions (Mine personally is 3k+ lines). I do agree that having all your functions in one file can get overwhelming but having them in one location beats having 30 ps1 files.

Comment: Actualy thats how the [link](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) does it too.

Comment: Their psm1 file is completely empty except for unblocking the files and dotsourcing them, i was thinkin i could combine both ways.

Comment: Well you can create a module file with a bunch of dot sourcing in it and it will work but that kinda defeats the purpose of a module IMO. However you can do this by using the example above inside a module to "dot source" multiple files and the simply `Import-Module`

Comment: I guess dotsourcing the functions within the module and refering to them within the psd1 file was the solution tnx

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to dotsourcing would be using the nested modules property of a manifest

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.1

You can list the relative paths to ps1 and psm1 files in the nested modules property of the psd1 manifest

You also need to list all the functions to export in the manifest as well. See also [Get List Of Functions From Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967449/get-list-of-functions-from-script)

Answer (score 0):

These are some steps I took ....

step 1:  Create a psm1 file with 2 simple function then export them both.
This works fine and as expected

Step 2: Create an external file with the name of the 3rd function.
PowerShell wont see the 3rd function

Step 3: Ad a dotsourcing line at the top of the module psm1 file.

PowerShell wont see the 3rd function

Step 4: Create a psd1file and add the 3rd function to 'FunctionsToExport'.
Powershell wont see the first two functions

Step 5: Add Those two functions to 'FunctionsToExport' in the psd1 file
PowerShell sees all the functions and everything works fine and as expected

Step 6: Comment out the dotsourcing codeline at the top of psm1 file
Function Three dissapears (This is the external function) when clicked
Function 1 and 2 within the psm1 file work fine.

Step 7: Add all files to the FileList Property of the psd1 file
Same Situation as Step 6

Step 8: Add the psm1 file to the ModuleList property of the psd1 file.
Same Situation as Step 6

Step 9: Add (external) function 3 to the ScriptsToProcess property of the psd1 file
Same Situation as Step 6

After taking these steps i dont see any other way then dotsourcing external ps1 files from within the psm1 file in conjuntion with telling about all of of the functions from within the psd1 file ... In this way all functions will be seen by powershell

Comment: My Dotsourcing codeline wich i took from the PSWindowsUpdate MOdule `Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.ps1 | Foreach-Object{ . $_.FullName }`

Comment: Because when you choose to export specific parts of your module, powershell ignore those that you don't export.

I have `Export-ModuleMember -Alias * -Function *` in my module, if i take out `-Function` i don't get **any** functions because i've specifically told powershell to export only aliases.

If there are 3 functions and you only add 1 to `FunctionsToExport` powershell will ignore 2 and only export 1.

Comment: true , i understand that, its just that wanted to know a deeper aspect of it i guess, and i think i also answered my own question i achieved why i even started this post for to get both cases work at once, now im left with a mini module example of how to achiev several cases :)

Comment: Where I am now completely convinced about now btw is that because of the fact that the psd1 file overrides any explicit exports from the psm1 file but does not fully include them with out a dotsource line within the psm1 file is that microsoft should give us that possibility, i think,it seems logic in one way but not completely

Comment: Wouldn't logic dictate that you put your function inside your module to avoid going to all this effort when there is an extremely simple and easy solution already in place(Functions in modules)?

Answer (score -1):

```
function Get-RunningServices {get-service | where-object {$_.Status -eq "running"}|Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Name| Sort-Object -property DisplayName}
```